# Clone CodeCommit from CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, aws-codebuild

Can you create a CodeBuild project which clones from initially one CodeCommit repo in the region, and then push the contents to a repo in another region?

I want to do it without using https credentials. I have a CodeBuild project which uses a role which assumes CodeCommitPowerUser access but the clone commands still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `region` is used to compute the credentials https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/customizations/codecommit.py#L147

Credentials generated for one region may not be used for a repository in other regions.